# Ignoring Fink's texlive in favor of a modern distribution

Tags: macos, fink

I have installed the latest version of MacTeX-2010, an oft-updated distribution of texlive.  However, after my last *fink update-all*, fink insists that its version of texlive (from 2008) is a requirement.  My question is,

> What should I do after installing fink's texlive so that my system completely ignores fink's version?

I am using OS.X 10.5.8 with fink 0.29.14.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all about paths.

Fink arranges to have `/sw/bin` in front of `/bin` and `/usr/bin` on your `$PATH` (so that fink tool can override the system tools). You need to arrange to have you 2010 tex installation come ahead of the fink one.

The usual place to do this would be in your `.bash_profile` (login shells) or `.bashrc` (non-login interactive shells) .

There may be other paths which need diddling, too.

---

An alternative would be to work with fink (talk to the current texlive maintainer, take over the texlive maintenance, or start a mactex package) to get a sufficiently up-to-date package.